# Setting Document as global property in java class, not working

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

In my Xpages application I have a java class in which I want to set a Document as global property and re-use across my methods. The Document represents a Notes configuration document and I want to perform the lookup only once. Unfortunately it is not working as expected. Perhaps someone can guide me to the proper process?

First I have set up a managed bean:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>emplDataMining</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>se.bank.employeeApp.utils.EmployeeDataMining</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

My class contains several methods who will go to different systems. All the URL's to the system are stored in a Notes configuration document, which I want to load only once and re-use across these methods

```
public class EmployeeDataMining implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Document configuration;

    //constructor class. not so very special, so I wont post it

    public void getConfiguration(){
        //setting up database and view
        //only 1 document stored in the view so I can hard-code the reference
        configuration = vw.getDocumentByKey("ConfigDocument", true);
        //... rest of code e.g. setting up httpclient, JSONobj
    }

    public void collectDataFromSystemX(CloseableHttpClient httpclient, Employee employee, JSONObject JSONobj){
        //I wont post all of my code  
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(this.configuration.getItemValueString("urlSystemX"));
        //this.configuration is null :-?
        //..rest of code
    }

    public void collectDataFromSystemY(CloseableHttpClient httpclient, Employee employee, JSONObject JSONobj){
        //I wont post all of my code  
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(this.configuration.getItemValueString("urlSystemY"));
        //this.configuration is null :-?
        //..rest of code
    }

}
```

My code is initiated from SSJS:

```
emplDataMining.getConfiguration(); 
emplDataMining.collectDataFromSystemX(//passing in the variables which are setup in getConfiguration method)
```

So my main concern is that the profile Document is not properly set or exchanged between the methods.

Can someone tell me what I have overlooked?

Comment: You should not store Domino objects as properties of serializable Java classes

Comment: Oops! I did not know this. Will try a different approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

- being view scoped the bean gets reloaded for every document you open. If it is a config document you want to use session scope
- You can’t store Notes objects in managed beans (request scope might work). What you do instead: in your bean’s constructor, load the document and extract the field values into bean internal variables (Strings, Lists etc). That will give you what you want

Comment: Thank you Stephan, this morning on my walk to work I was thinking about storing the internal variables as string in the bean. Thank you for confirming my thoughts!

Comment: If it's a global config document then I would recommend to use application scope instead of session scope

Comment: Do not use applicationScope. You will need to restart HTTP task (or similar method) to refresh values if your config document changes. viewScope is the best option, IMO.

Comment: Or have a refresh() method you expose that your admin page calls after saving the config document

Comment: Agree with Stephan Wissel. With application scope you of course need to maintain caching and refreshing of the cache but it improves performance instead of using view scope.